# Can't install a forked npm repo

Tags: npm

I am trying to install https://github.com/dtinth/gulp-rev via `npm install git+https://github.com/dtinth/gulp-rev.git` but it continually installs the parent repo.  I have tried to clear the npm cache, but that doesn't seem to help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

npm docs indicate that you can pass a url to a tarball, so maybe try

```
npm install https://github.com/dtinth/gulp-rev/tarball/4a64235a1c97df3906a52f6b52405222ec80bab2
```

note the tarball and the revision hash in the github url